# Alternative to std::ifstream for eosio contract

Tags: smart-contract, c++, eosiocpp

I'm watching for an alternative to "std::ifstream" because "#include " can't include as header in a contract.

My code is:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Record& data)
{
    return str >> data.from >> data.to >> data.rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the basic CPP string concatenation syntax. Smart contracts should not be bloated. istream is a heavyweight which handles locales and other considerations that are irrelevant to this use case.